# are there APIs to get some statistics from twitter

Tags: php, twitter, hashtag

I have a task to create a dynamic page (PHP or Javascript) that shows:

1. Number of tweets with specific hash tag
2. Number of tweets that came from specific country!!
3. most popular hash-tags for specific country

does anybody have any idea of how to get such stats or part of them??
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should really search more because there's a lot of information out there on this - start at the Twitter [API Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs).

1. You use it as a [search term](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)
2. Try https://dev.twitter.com/docs/places/finding-tweets-about-places
3. Combine 1. & 2.

Answer (score 1):

No. Twitter releases its statistics after a certain period of time. There's **no definitive/official API for that**. But there are a lot of third-party applications that offer that.

[InsideTwitter](http://www.sysomos.com/insidetwitter/)

[Twitter by Country](http://www.google.com.ng/url?url=http://www.sysomos.com/insidetwitter/#countries&rct=j&q=twitter%20statistics%20by%20country&usg=AFQjCNHFSMpoBIQmrsOLOVa0qNNYhrKFZA&sa=X&ei=4e2KToW_F-ag4gTOpunlAw&ved=0CC4QygQwAQ)

[Twitter Counter](http://twittercounter.com/)